# Storing links in a session?

Tags: php, session, hyperlink

I want to store links in a session or multiple sessions and I was wondering what would be the best way to do this..

I was thinking that I could use a for loop with sessions foreach session as $s .... But then I would need $session1, $session2, $session3, etc.

Thanks in advance,

--I'm a PHP noob.

Comment: Have you considered using an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays in sessions:

```
$_SESSION['links'] = array('example.com', 'example2.com');

foreach ($_SESSION['links'] as $link) {
  // Do something with $link
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Also, I was wondering.. How could I add to that array? I want to keep adding links to an array then to echo all of the links out?

Comment: As easy as: `$_SESSION['links'][] = 'example3.com';` :)

Comment: So then, if I echoed $_SESSION['links']; I would get example1.com example2.com and example3.com?

Comment: Not directly, as `$_SESSION['links']` in a [PHP array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you'll need to loop through it with a `for`, or `foreach` loop, like in the code above. For each of the iterations in that loop, `$link` will contain a single item from your links array

Comment: I don't quite understand, sorry - I'm quite new to PHP and am just tinkering.. 

So, would the foreach loop be the same as the one above or different?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the link really, are you trying to output it to the screen, store it to a database, or something different?